# How to wirte a query that with ' left join a subquery ' in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

````
SELECT tool.*,IF(b.id,TRUE,NULL) as liked FROM tool LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM user_tool_like WHERE uid = '4d63a2bcae8e11eda9cf68fef7020cbc'
) as b  ON tool.id = b.tid
ORDER BY
tool.create_time DESC 
LIMIT 0,10

subquery = db.session.query(UserToolLike).filter_by(uid=user['uid']).subquery()

query = db.session.query(Tool,subquery.id).outerjoin(subquery,Tool.id == subquery.tid)

page = db.paginate(query.order_by(desc(Tool.create_time)))
print(page)```
````

#############################################

File "/Users/coderd/Desktop/mypms/toolking/toolking-api/app/api/v1/tool.py", line 48, in get_tool_list
query = db.session.query(Tool,subquery.id).outerjoin(subquery,Tool.id == subquery.tid)
AttributeError: 'Subquery' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the id attribute on the subquery object, which is not a valid attribute. You can use the exists() method of the subquery to check whether a record exists in the subquery. Try the below instead.

```
SELECT tool.*, EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM user_tool_like WHERE user_tool_like.uid = 
    '4d63a2bcae8e11eda9cf68fef7020cbc' AND tool.id = user_tool_like.tid
    ) AS liked
FROM tool
ORDER BY tool.create_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```